# Display total of returned array in ELM

Tags: elm

I'm new to ELM, and I'm extending a basic app that displays a presentation from a markdown document.

I'm changing the main.elm document of [this](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/stirring-chokeberry?path=src/Main.elm:191:17) glitch app to show a total of the available pages.

If I set the total when I get the response (in this block)

```
RcvSlides resp ->
    case resp of
        Ok slides ->
            ( { model
                | slides = Just <| Array.fromList <| String.split "^^^^" slides
              }
            , Cmd.none
            )

        Err _ ->
            ( { model | slides = Nothing }
            , Cmd.none
            )
```

I always get 0, if I do it in the NextSlide case, I can get the total, but not in the first page.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please make a [mcve] and include it, along with all relevant information, in the question itself. Stack Overflow is meant to be a knowledge base of useful questions and answers, not a help desk. This isn't going to be very useful once the code on glitch changes or it goes out of service entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you forgot to set `total` when you receive your slides. [Here a working version of your glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/flaxen-index?path=src/Main.elm:94:30):

```
RcvSlides resp ->
    case resp of
        Ok slides ->
            let
                nextSlides = Array.fromList <| String.split "^^^^" slides
                nextTotal = Array.length nextSlides
                nextModel = { model
                    | slides = Just <| nextSlides
                    , total = nextTotal
                    }
            in
            ( nextModel, Cmd.none )

        Err _ ->
            ( { model | slides = Nothing }
            , Cmd.none
            )
```